# Stop Safari-Mobile from converting 7 digits numbers into "tel" format

Tags: feature-request, design

I have noticed that Safari (mobile) <sup>**1**</sup> converts 7 digits numbers into *anchor* with `tel` attribute. To stop this behavior of Safari, `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />` tag should be added.

To produce this issue, from your *iDevice*, check any question with views over one million e.g. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/1771795).

[image: converted into "tel"]

---

[image: page's source]

<sup>**1** iPad 2 (iOS 8.0.2)</sup>

Comment: My reaction? *Meh*, not *really* a problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's not significant but it breaks the design.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how is it not a problem? Just because it's not a big issue doesn't mean it shouldn't be fixed. It's clearly not how it's supposed to look.

Comment: I suggest that it would be bad design to have SO emit special code to cover overzealous behavior by one browser. What should a news site do if it reports "Apple to hire 1534911 employees to implement hidden six-finger touch command". There was a time when it made sense to code exceptions for IE6 because of its dominance. If a modern browser renders a page incorrectly, take it up the the browser vendor. (And, no, I didn't recently blow a bunch of time helping a friend turn off "The annoying assistive technologies thing that hovers over the everything else". Ok, I did.)

Comment: Reproduced in IE11, too. I see it as a Skype link in the Metro app. The Skype extension for IE also recognizes it in desktop mode.

Comment: @msw [Looks like IE supports that meta tag too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/dn265018(v=vs.85).aspx) so not just one browser.

Comment: Testing: 911 a 123 a 1234 a 12345 a 1234567 a 12345678 a 123456789 a 1234567890

Comment: Reach out to Apple? It does the same in iBooks, and is *fantastically* annoying.

Comment: I guess this should be migrated to _Meta SE_ as it "will" affect all SE sites.

Comment: @msw A news site should report "Apple to hire over 1.5 million employees" instead of mentioning that entire number as if those 35,000 "over" people are relevant to the general public. General news rules: if a number is bigger than 200 or so, round it, because the audience can't really imagine something when they hear 1534911, while they can if they hear 1.5 million. Totally off-topic, I know, but thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 59):

Additionally/alternatively, numbers like this with four or more digits could have commas separators added to prevent them from being detected as telephone numbers (`1,534,911` instead of `1534911`) . This change would be consistent in style with other parts of the site, such as the [questions counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) pictured below.

[image]

Comment: I really dislike the comma separators, as commas are used as decimal separator in some countries.

Comment: This site *already* uses comma separators as you can see. If anything, adding them to the view count would simply make the site more consistent. Besides, this site is in English and therefore commas are correct. It's not correct to imply that using commas is confusing on an English language website.

Comment: @NickG I'm not sure that English means it has to be commas used for separators.

Comment: Of course it does. English speaking countries would *never* use a comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: @NickG Yes, as answer says that they are already used on site, and I was hinting that maybe those could be changed too. SO has a lot of users from non-english speaking countries, and taking into account little things like this would increase usability for them. Note that I'm not against digit grouping, just don't use commas.

Comment: Use a space instead of a comma and you obtain the same effect but in an unambiguous way (even for non-English speakers).

Comment: I agree using a comma to separate the numbers. The argument that `commas are used as decimal separators in some countries` doesn't make sense as we already have decimal points when a user has high rep (eg. `14.2k`). So I think it would make sense to most people.

Comment: There would be perfect clarity in this instance for two other reasons. 1) Fractional views make no logical sense. 2) Seven digit numbers would have TWO commas.

Comment: @user694733 creating some pseudo-locale is not the way to go imho. Currently, all SE sites (except pt.SO) are available under the en-US (American English) locale, so a comma is the thousands separator. Adding support for other locales could be done, but I'm not sure if it makes sense with all content being in English.

Comment: Not that I think it's important, but [Indian english numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Numbering_System) uses seperators at thousands, lakh and crore instead of thousands, millions and billions (eg: 10,00,000) - although I'm comfortable with either. I find it harder to read numbers without any separators than those with the Arabic style though. Metric FTW!

Comment: @Bakuriu Then any sane telephone-number-parser would parse that as a number. Commas have the advantage of not being used in phone numbers.

Comment: @nishantjr **Geolocation**. If the request comes from an Indian IP, it should be shown the Indian comma convention, and if not, the international comma convention. Similarly, connections from all IPs from non-*American English*-speaking countries should be shown the site UI elements in British English instead, since that is more common globally.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I'm not in India :P  ... Don't browsers send the locale information to the server?

Comment: @nishantjr They do, but they prompt for user confirmation first. If this site asks to see the user's location, that would seem weird to users who don't know that it's being used for localization, right?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi You're mixing several things. Using GeoIP sucks because it is about the user's preference, not his accidental (apparent) origin of the connection. I'm Dutch and I'd hate to have dutch options. And INDEED, the browser sends **locale** settings. And **no**, the browser will **not** prompt for this. You're confusing with **location** - which would be a privacy-sensitive thing and the browser might prompt about that (if no blanket permission was already obtained). _Note that \@damryfbfnetsi was saying exactly the same, but you missed the clues_